# Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'job-dir' running on google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a training job on google cloud but I get the following error:

> FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'job-dir'. Did
>   you mean: log_dir ?

This is the command:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training JOB16 
--job-dir gs://rltrd 
--module-name trainer.agent 
--package-path trainer/ --region us-east1 
--config trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml 
--python-version 3.5 
--runtime-version 1.14
```

In main I have included the code from the google samples but it does not solve the problem. I get the same error when I try to run it on my local machine.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument(
        '--job-dir',
         help='GCS location to write checkpoints and export models')
args = parser.parse_args()
arguments = args.__dict__ 
job_dir = arguments.pop('job_dir')
```

Comment: Is it working for other parameters ? What's your python version? Are you on Linux/Mac or Windows?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, the other parameters are working. I am using Windows with python 3.7 but runtime version is 3.5

Comment: What's your `gcloud version` ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Google Cloud SDK 258.0.0
bq 2.0.46
core 2019.08.09
gsutil 4.42

Comment: Can you perform a try by replacing `ai-platform` by `ml-engine`? I successfully run a training job last week with my legacy code using `ml-engine` command.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It's the same I just get a warning that ml-engine will be deprecated

Comment: Wait, I read again your problem and your last paragraph disturbed me. You try to get the --job-dir, in your own python code? Is it an issue of Gcloud command or in your code ?